# How to project (transform) an array of FileInfo to a list of strings with fsharp

Tags: f#

What I am trying is something like this:

```
let getFiles path =  (directoryInfo path).GetFiles().ToList
```

but this gives me a list of FileInfos instead of list of strings. How can I project this to a list of strings?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the paths associated with each file you can do:

```
let getFiles path = (directoryInfo path).GetFiles() |> Array.map (fun fi -> fi.FullName) |> List.ofSeq
```

Note this creates an F# list, not a `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`. IF you want to create one of these you can use `ResizeArray`:

```
let getFiles path = (DirectoryInfo path).GetFiles() |> Array.map (fun fi -> fi.FullName) |> (fun s -> ResizeArray<_>(s))
```

EDIT: As the comment points out, since `GetFiles` returns an array, you can use `Array.map` and avoid converting into a list/resize array if you don't need it.

Comment: And if you want to return a simple array (which is what `GetFiles` returns btw) you should use `|> Array.map (fun ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by Lee is correct, but this is easier:

```
open System.IO

let filenames = Directory.EnumerateFiles path |> Seq.toList
```

[Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) returns `string seq`, but if you're happy with an array, you can  use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) instead.